# Is it possible to create real dropdown fire handler with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

With the following example, I want to change the dropdown val, like the way, if I click at it - but the script seemes not to fire like a mouseclick at the dropdown, because the alert message doesn´t appear.

```
$("#Filters").change(function() { 
  alert( "Handler for .change() called." );
});

$(".button.two").click(function () {   
  $("#provider").val(".option_two");  
});

$(".button.three").click(function () {    
  $("#provider").val(".option_three");    
});
```

[My fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p3dcsjbp/)

I also try:

```
$(document).on('change', '#Filters', function(){
        alert( "Handler for .change() called." );
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After changing the value trigger change event manually.

```
$("#Filters").change(function() { 
  alert( "Handler for .change() called." );
});

$(".button.two").click(function () {   
  $("#provider").val(".option_two").change();  
});

$(".button.three").click(function () {    
  $("#provider").val(".option_three").change();    
});
```

Comment: You're welcome. If it works than please accept as answer.

Comment: I have to wait, till I can accept it (stackoverflow countdown) ;)